# Python equivalent of zip for dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

If I have these two lists:

```
la = [1, 2, 3]
lb = [4, 5, 6]
```

I can iterate over them as follows:

```
for i in range(min(len(la), len(lb))):
    print la[i], lb[i]
```

Or more pythonically

```
for a, b in zip(la, lb):
    print a, b
```

---

What if I have two dictionaries?

```
da = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
db = {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
```

Again, I can iterate manually:

```
for key in set(da.keys()) & set(db.keys()):
    print key, da[key], db[key]
```

Is there some builtin method that allows me to iterate as follows?

```
for key, value_a, value_b in common_entries(da, db):
    print key, value_a, value_b
```

Comment: @Eric python builtins are made usually because of their popularity. This is not used often enough to make it a builtin

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is no built-in function or method that can do this. However, you could easily define your own.

```
def common_entries(*dcts):
    if not dcts:
        return
    for i in set(dcts[0]).intersection(*dcts[1:]):
        yield (i,) + tuple(d[i] for d in dcts)
```

This builds on the "manual method" you provide, but, like `zip`, can be used for any number of dictionaries.

```
>>> da = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> db = {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
>>> list(common_entries(da, db))
[('c', 3, 6), ('b', 2, 5), ('a', 1, 4)]
```

When only one dictionary is provided as an argument, it essentially returns `dct.items()`.

```
>>> list(common_entries(da))
[('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

With no dictionaries, it returns an empty generator (just like `zip()`)

```
>>> list(common_entries())
[]
```

Comment: [Change1:] Also, sticking to the `zip(*seq)-->seq` contract, i suggest to return `key, (values, tuple, ...)` so as to mimic a dictionary.
[Change2:] Finally a better name would be `zipdic(*map)-->map`.

Comment: Doesn't work on python 3. `----> 5     yield (i,) + tuple(d[i] for d in dcts)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Answer (score 14):

The object returned by `dict.keys()` (called a dictionary key view) [acts like a `set` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), so you can just take the [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) of the keys:

```
da = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 7}
db = {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 9}

common_keys = da.keys() & db.keys()

for k in common_keys:
    print(k, da[k], db[k])
```

On Python 2 you'll need to convert the keys to `set`s yourself:

```
common_keys = set(da) & set(db)

for k in common_keys:
    print k, da[k], db[k]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#:~:text=Keys%20views%20are,sausage%27%2C%20%27bacon%27%2C%20%27spam%27%7D

Answer (score 6):

[Dictionary key views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) are already set-like in Python 3.  You can remove `set()`:

```
for key in da.keys() & db.keys():
    print(key, da[key], db[key])
```

In Python 2:

```
for key in da.viewkeys() & db.viewkeys():
    print key, da[key], db[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone is looking for generalized solution:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce


def zip_mappings(*mappings):
    keys_sets = map(set, mappings)
    common_keys = reduce(set.intersection, keys_sets)
    for key in common_keys:
        yield (key,) + tuple(map(operator.itemgetter(key), mappings))
```

or if you like to separate key from values and use syntax like

```
for key, (values, ...) in zip_mappings(...):
    ...
```

we can replace last line with

```
yield key, tuple(map(operator.itemgetter(key), mappings))
```

---

#### Tests

```
from collections import Counter


counter = Counter('abra')
other_counter = Counter('kadabra')
last_counter = Counter('abbreviation')
for (character,
     frequency, other_frequency, last_frequency) in zip_mappings(counter,
                                                                 other_counter,
                                                                 last_counter):
    print('character "{}" has next frequencies: {}, {}, {}'
          .format(character,
                  frequency,
                  other_frequency,
                  last_frequency))
```

gives us

```
character "a" has next frequencies: 2, 3, 2
character "r" has next frequencies: 1, 1, 1
character "b" has next frequencies: 1, 1, 2
```

(tested on `Python 2.7.12` & `Python 3.5.2`)

Answer (score 0):

Python3: How about the following?

```py
da = {'A': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
db = {'B': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
for key, (value_a, value_b) in  {k:(da[k],db[k]) for k in set(da)&set(db)}.items():
  print(key, value_a, value_b)
```

The above snippet prints values of common keys ('b' and 'c') and discards the keys which don't match ('A' and 'B').

In order to include all keys into the output we could use a slightly modified comprehension: `{k:(da.get(k),db.get(k)) for k in set(da)|set(db)}`.

Comment: This is closer to `itertools.izip_longest` than it is to `zip`. As written, this gives `ValueError`.